# Why is the evaluation map of sheaves injective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E$ be a globally generated vector bundle of rank $r$. Let $V$ be a subspace of $H^0(S,E)$ of dimension $r$. We have the evaluation map $ev:V\otimes \mathcal{O}_S\longrightarrow E$. Why is this map injective?

If $H^0(S,E)$ has as basis $s_1,\cdots, s_n$ and $V$ has as basis $s_1,\cdots,s_r$, then $ev$ sends the standard basis $e_i$ to $s_i$, for $i=i,\cdots,r$. At the stalk level, it is map between two free modules of rank r, $O_x\longrightarrow E_x$, sending ${(e_i)}_x$ to ${(s_i)}_x$, again $i:i,\cdots,r$. But these $(s_i)_x$ may not be a basis for $E_x$. So why is it injective?

Comment: The homomorphismm $\text{ev}$ is not necessarily injective if $S$ is reducible or nonreduced (I assume that your $X$ and your $S$ are the same).  If $S$ is reducible and reduced, then a global section of $E$ is zero if and only if it is zero at the generic point.  Thus, the stalk of $\text{ev}$ at the generic point is injective.  A homomorphism of locally free sheaves (or even just torsion-free, coherent sheaves) on an integral scheme is injective.

Comment: @JasonStarr: I think you mean a homomorphism of torsion-free coherent sheaves which is injective at the generic point of an integral scheme is injective.  Any homomorphism of locally free sheaves on an integral scheme is certainly not injective.  Just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take, for instance, $E = O(1) \oplus O(1)$ on $P^1$ and the space $V$ to be the global sections of the first summand. Then the evaluation map $V\otimes O \to E$ factors as 
$$
V \otimes O \to O(1) \hookrightarrow O(1) \oplus O(1) = E.
$$
So, its kernel is $O(-1)$ and it is not injective.

Comment: @Sasha, thanks! But doesn't this happen? This is also referred to in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118971/globally-generated-subvector-bundles-and-evaluation-maps. What is different here? Maybe that $r\geq 2$